# Travelling with beach sand in carry-on

Tags: air-travel, usa, airport-security, hand-luggage

I'm making a trip back home (to the coast) shortly, and I would like to bring back sand from the beach with me as a keepsake or memento. It's just a short weekend trip, and I won't be checking any luggage, so I was wondering if it's even worth bothering trying to bring sand aboard the plane in my carry-on?

If so, what can I do to make the security screening as smooth as possible? I was planning on putting the sand in sandwich-sized plastic bags, enclosed in a larger quart- or gallon-sized bag.

Comment: Rub your beach towel in the sand and pack it in normally !!! at home, just collect everything! :-)

Comment: I went to Italy for a month and was afraid to bring it back with me in my bags because they were really strict so I bough my kids a couple cheap outfits and wrapped it up and shipped it from the post office to my house it came 3 weeks later ‍♀️

Comment: @Tfhshev Whether taking it yourself or sending per post, it's still illegal in Sardinia - so it's really nothing to boast about. [Why Sardinia's tourists taking sand as souvenir face fine - BBC News](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-41031029)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It isn't a weapon, tool, flammable, explosive, chemical or liquid, so I can't imagine that it would be a problem. It isn't listed by the [TSA as a prohibited item](http://www.tsa.gov/travelers/airtravel/prohibited/permitted-prohibited-items.shtm). I'd say just put it in the bottom of your bag and not worry about it.

If you are travelling internationally, you may have an issue with customs depending on your country of origin and destination, but it isn't a concern from a security screening perspective.

Answer (score 28):

While I was going to add this as a comment, I think it's more suitable as what SHOULD be the answer.

While it may be fun to do, environmentally you really shouldn't do it.  In addition to potential disease transfers, bugs or contamination, if everyone did this, think how it'd affect the beach!  You're essentially doing what would take erosion a lot longer to achieve, and is really not a good idea.

Further reading on countries / places where it's been a big problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sand_theft

Note that they're now actively [fining people in Italy](https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/sardinia-beach-sand-scli-intl/index.html) for doing this.

[Updated article on CNN today about sand theft problems and fines](https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/sardinia-sand-seized-scli-intl/index.html).

Comment: I'm sure taking away a bit of sand would never hurt. :)

Comment: We're just bitter in the South Island here because sand from our glorious beaches is being taken up north to make nicer beaches for Wellington (the capital).  Cue 'forecasts' of the island shrinking ;)

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee if a million tourists each take away a pound of sand, that's half a million pounds of sand removed from a beach. On a small island that's a lot.

Comment: I always hate such 'calculations' because nobody - not even the OP - here is talking about taking away a POUND of sand.

Comment: Nor does he mention bringing 999,999 friends. While @MarkMayo makes an interesting point, I really doubt taking a pinch of sand is going to have a measurable environmental impact.

Comment: The removal of sand from beaches is actually enough of a problem to be outlawed in some places.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee a pound isn't that much: it's a little more than a cup. OP says "I was planning on putting the sand in sandwich-sized plastic bags", so who knows, maybe a pound.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee your mindset it's exactly the one that causes the problems in my opinion. I personally saw people taking away more than one bottle of sand because "that would never hurt". Actually it's the reason why it's outlawed in some places as TRiG says, for example in Sardinia (italy). Take a look at "la pelosa" and "budelli" beach in sardinia, there they had this problem...Taking away sand from the sahara it's not a big deal, but taking it from a small beach with a unique type of sand wich is visited from hundred of thousands of tourists each year, __will hurt__

Comment: And think about how much it would be a problem for the environment if everybody in Europe and America would use an airplane ;)

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee some take 88 pounds(!) - A French couple was threatened with jail time in 2019 after 14 plastic bottles containing around 40 kilograms (88 pounds) of white sand were found in their car as they waited to board a ferry.  (https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/sardinia-sand-seized-scli-intl/index.html)

Answer (score 15):

Internationally is a problem for soil, but not domestic. You shouldn't have an issue with TSA at all.

Comment: Do you have any official information about it?

Comment: No official info, but when I came back from Afghanistan it was one of the big things they checked for. The security screeners told us domestic wasn't an issue, the only problem was internationally because of diseases not native to North America being brought over.

Comment: most countries bar the import of biological materials, and that includes soil, without a special license. This can lead to high fines, expulsion, even prison for carrying things as seemingly harmless as an apple or a tuna sandwich off an international flight.

Comment: @jwenting in my experience bringing good such as apples and sandwiches generally leads to confiscation and destruction of the item, but no additional punishment unless the traveler was deceptive.

Comment: @phoog and failure to list those items on a customs form can be deemed "deceptive", especially if the traveler goes on to try and argue with the customs officers.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a problem with TSA.
Last year, the only suitcase that was opened by the TSA was the one with a small bottle of sand.

The airport was San Fransisco
The destination was Europe

Comment: What do you mean? You were carrying sand and had several suitcases on this trip, they opened only that one and had no objection against the sand?

Comment: You are right.
Besides the sand, all suitcases where the same (clothes, souvenirs, ...)
The bottle of sand may be opaque to XRays. Bottles were not removed from the suitcase

Comment: "The airport was San Francisco The destination was Europe"..this sounds really weird in an international (non-US) forum..

Answer (score 3):

I brought black sand back to Canada from Dominica (an island in the Caribbean) last month. I kept the sand in a water bottle and I travelled carry on only. When TSA opened my bag, they asked me what it was and I told them “oh that’s some black sand I brought home with me from Dominica. I’m going to put it in a bottle and keep it as a trinket to look at” TSA shrugged and let me keep the sand. My advice is don’t act nervous, be honest, and everything should sail smoothly. When you’re cool with security, they’re cool with you.

Answer (score 2):

I had a small amount of beach sand from a Florida beach and it was confiscated by TSA agents at the Tampa airport. The sand came from a relatives beachfront home and they said it was ok for me to have it.

Answer (score 2):

TSA held up my backpack containing a bag of beach sand. They did a chemical test for explosives on it, then sent me on my way. Eugene, Oregon.